# Re-writing Windows-like app, rendering engine of IE7/8 with the new one

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, rest, soap

I've got a case scenario, where I need to re-develop a WPF app similar to 'Windows' containing a task-bar (with some menus, search field, bookmarks), multiple windows (workspace) with complex web-based views (HTML5/CSS3), drag and drop functionality in between them and some sort of a task manager controlling windows and common UI. Also, the app is to communicate with other (.NET, JAVA, C++) apps across the intranet and possibly the internet.

1. My question is, for the above scenario, what rendering engines should be considered? (Currently IE7)
2. MVC vs MVP vs MVVM ? or perhaps anything else?
3. SOAP vs REST ?

Please note, that the app is to be used by Win XP/7/8 users.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of 100k questions combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **My question is, for the above scenario, what rendering engines should be considered? (Currently IE7)**

   How about all of them? The days of developing an app for a single browser went out with the `<blink>` tag in the 90's. You want WebKit (Safari/Chrome/virtually every mobile browser), Gecko (Firefox), and Triton (IE), as well as Blink, now, which Chrome will use henceforth. Though, for the time being, it's still pretty much the same as WebKit. In terms of IE support, if you have to support Windows XP, you'll require at least IE 8 support (perhaps even IE 7 as well), which will be very limiting for your app. You might want to consider a "bare essentials" approach for those versions of IE and then worry about the higher level stuff in modern browsers only. With IE 10+, Chrome, and Firefox rendering will all be pretty much the same. Something may be a pixel off here or there, but the days of completely different rendering from browser to browser are thankfully pretty much over. You will however, need to concern yourself with feature-level support in each browser. Chrome and IE 11 have support for WebGL, for instance whereas other browsers and versions may not, even among modern ones. Depending on what features your app will utilize, you'll need to make use of polyfills or abstraction libraries.
2. **MVC vs MVP vs MVVM ? or perhaps anything else?**

   No one can answer this for you. It's going to depend on your app and development team. In general, though, I'd stay away from Web Forms and use the MVC framework, though that's not necessarily the same as using "MVC". The typical approach tends to be a combo of MVC and MVVM: using the concept of Model, View, and Controller from ASP.NET MVC along with the addition of View Models to represent your database-backed entities in your views and mapping from one to the other manually or with something like AutoMapper.
3. **SOAP vs REST ?**

   This also depends on your specific circumstances. Though, if you have a choice at all, go with REST all the way. Anything new should be based on REST. Only use SOAP for interop with legacy platforms.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a joke, it's pretty funny!